# Get random number with key

Tags: php, random

I need to get a random number with `mt_srand` and `mt_rand` but my code not work good i have many time the same number its not totaly random

```
$key = "8f49ba1f21a3d41b2ec7999dd1e246265d6d3f0ccf809695901d34c3b9152991";

$cr = substr($key, 0, 5);
mt_srand(crc32($cr));
$num[0] = mt_rand(1,50);

$cr = substr($key, 5, 10);
mt_srand(crc32($cr));
$num[1] = mt_rand(1,50);

$cr = substr($key, 10, 15);
mt_srand(crc32($cr));
$num[2] = mt_rand(1,50);
```

crc32 its good for mt_srand with alphanumeric key ? In local i work with windows 32bit and server is debian 7 64bit

Thanks

Comment: in general there is no need to seed, i it will do it for you

Comment: have you tried using the unique_id() http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: yes but i need seed for reget the same number after

Comment: " reget the same number" no idea what the means.

Comment: @Netzach mt_rand produces a much tru-er random number.

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to use an RNG as a randomized hash function. Don't do that. Use a real randomized hash function, and follow it's instructions. Never "roll your own" crypto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only use `mt_srand()` once. It's purpose is to seed a number generator, constantly seeding it with the same type of value and same bitlength will cause problems with numbers being truly random.

Since you're passing in a string which has the possibility of being [type juggled](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to the int that `mt_srand()` requires, sometimes the string will evaluate to a correct number, but most times it will evaluate to `0` or `null`.

Depending on the speed of the `crc32()` function, `mt_rand()` might receive the same initial value (probably 0) and same clock tick (which is what `mt_rand()` uses to generate a random number) which will produce the same number.

In many cases, you don't even need to seed the random number generator because PHP will handle that for you.

[`mt_srand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php)

> Note: There is no need to seed the random number generator with srand() or mt_srand() as this is done automatically.

just remove the `mt_srand()` calls or keep only one.

```
$key = "8f49ba1f21a3d41b2ec7999dd1e246265d6d3f0ccf809695901d34c3b9152991";

$num[0] = mt_rand(1,50);
$num[1] = mt_rand(1,50);
$num[2] = mt_rand(1,50);
```